# an integration by parts question

Tags: calculus, integration

Can integral by parts solve this Integral?
$$\int\arcsin(x)\arccos(x)dx$$
If no how I can solve this integral?

Comment: Mathematica produces $$2 x - Sqrt[1 - x^2] ArcSin[x] + 
 ArcCos[x] (Sqrt[1 - x^2] + x ArcSin[x]) .$$ The Maple code $$J := int(arcsin(x)*arccos(x), x):
with(IntegrationTools):
Parts(J, arcsin(x));
  $$ outputs $$\left( x\arccos \left( x \right) -\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1} \right) \arcsin
 \left( x \right) +2\,x+\arccos \left( x \right) \sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1}
 .$$

Comment: The Maple code $$with(Student[Calculus1]):
IntTutor(arcsin(x)*arccos(x), x);
 $$ outputs $$\int\arcsin \left( x \right) \arccos \left( x \right){dx}= \left( 
x\arccos \left( x \right) -\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1} \right) \arcsin \left( x
 \right) -\int \frac {x\arccos \left( x \right) -\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1}
}{\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1}}{dx}

 .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \arcsin(x) \arccos(x) dx = \arcsin(x) \int \arccos(x)dx - \int \left( \frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin(x)) \int \arccos(x)\right ) dx $$
You can use integration by parts to evaluate $ \displaystyle \int \arccos(x)dx$ as

\begin{align*}
\int \arccos(x) dx  &=  \arccos(x)\int dx - \int \left( - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}  \int  dx \right )dx \\ 
 &= x \arccos(x) + \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx  \\ 
 &= x \arccos(x) - \sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{align*}
So you get, 
$$\int \arccos(x) \arcsin(x) dx  
=  \arcsin(x)(x \arccos(x) - \sqrt{1-x^2}) - \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(x \arccos(x) - \sqrt{1-x^2}) dx $$
The latter integral can be evaluated again by parts
\begin{align*}
 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(x \arccos(x) - \sqrt{1-x^2}) dx   &= \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \arccos(x) dx - \int  dx  \\ 
&= \arccos(x) \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx - \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx - x \\
&= - \arccos(x) \sqrt{1-x^2} - 2x
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

The question is more or less equivalent to "Can I compute the primitive of $\arcsin{x}$?"  The answer is yes because

$$\int dx \, \arcsin{x} = x \arcsin{x} - \int dx \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = x \arcsin{x} + \sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$

Now you may use integration by parts in your integral:

$$\begin{align}\int dx \, \arcsin{x} \arccos{x}  &= \arccos{x} \left [ x \arcsin{x} + \sqrt{1-x^2}\right ] + \int dx \frac{x \arcsin{x} + \sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\ &= \arccos{x} \left [ x \arcsin{x} + \sqrt{1-x^2}\right ] + x - \sqrt{1-x^2} \arcsin{x} + x + C\end{align}$$

That last integral was also done by parts.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int \arcsin x \arccos x \, dx = \int \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin x \right)\arcsin x \, dx $$

Substitute $ x = \sin u, \: dx = \cos u \, du $ and the integral becomes:

$$ \int \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - u \right)u \cos u \, du 
= \frac{\pi}{2} \int u \cos u \, du - \int u^2 \cos u \, du $$

Now you can evaluate each integral individually (by parts)